# Youtube Data API : Insert a video validation process

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to insert videos using the Youtube Data Api.

My code is working, I can see the video on Youtube, but the video becomes private instantly because my application has not been approved.

So I'm trying to approve the application, I created an external UI ( only one html page ) which explains how to use it, and anybody can use it from it.
I'm getting emails from Youtube saying my application looks like a staging/dev application but does not give any more details.

Does anyone know what I should have in the UI ? or does anyone have an example of application running using the Youtube Data Api ?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the domains and redirect uris you have set?

Comment: @DaImTo the site is live, but I prefer not to share it yet, the urls don't include the environment if this is what you are asking.

Comment: No i want to make sure that its not localhost, can you at least give me the domain extension are they all .com's?  are they all HTTPS?    I have a video on what you need to do to become verified https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8  most of the time if they say its in dev mode its because you have a redirect uri thats localhost or not https.    I have also seen them complain about .dev domains

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try to find on youtube ( big mistake ). the site is stored on a S3 bucket, using http only, I'm gonna watch the video and follow the advice. I didn't think of the https or the .com domain

Comment: Try and send google an email letting them konw that its stored on an S3 bucket that only supports http,  im not sure anyone has gotten past that road block yet.  It needs to be https or they are not going to verify it. Let me know what they say.